# yadcf filter with select tag inside column

Tags: datatables, filtering, yadcf

I have a table (using datatables framwork) which contains in a column  tag. I mean that content of this columns looks like this:

```
<td>
  <select class="form-control attendance_select" data-id_player="130">
    <option value="-1">No</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">No answer</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

When I use yadcf column filter and try to search only columns wih "Yes" as selected options in this select, it doesn't work because every rows contains "Yes" in html code.

Can you please help me, how to set yadcf for solving this issue if it's possible?

Thank you

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle/etc sample page, in general the solution should use the `filter_type: 'custom_func'` for that column, read about the custom [function api / signature](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/61f8ee76d432f129490d77a2b96339e305f1b305/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L38) - not entirely sure if its possible without updating datatables model on input state change

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to define filter type "custom_func" and specify a custom filter function for your column.

From [inline docs:](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) (reformatted explanation )

> custom_func
>
> Required: true, when filter_type is custom_func
>   
>  Type:               function
>   
>  Default value:      undefined
>   
>  Description:        should be pointing to a function with the following signature

```
function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal, rowValues, stateVal) {

}
```

> where `filterVal`: is the value from the select box,
>   
>  `columnVal` is the value from the relevant row column,
>   
>  `rowValues` is an array that holds the values of
>   the entire row and
>   
>  `stateVal` which holds the current state of the
>   table row DOM
>   
> , stateVal is perfect to handle situations in which you placing radiobuttons / checkbox inside table column (should be suitable for your case of `select`. 
>   
> This function should return *true if the row matches your condition* and the row should be displayed) and false otherwise.